# Can't logon with Joomla IIS 8 install

Tags: security, login, installation, iis

I have a virtual server on Microsoft Azure. It has IIS 8, PHP 5.4 and a Joomla 3.3 site installed on it. This is a brand new install where I am migrating a site from a different location using Akeeba Backup(v4.0.2).

I am seeing a problem when I try to log into the Joomla site at either the front end or the administrator side. In both cases I enter a valid username/password combination (verified) and the screen just jumps back to the same page.  I get no error or notification of an invalid login, but it does not log in.

I verified the users I am trying and everything looks good at that level.  I have error reporting set to its highest level in PHP and Joomla. So far I have seen no errors anyplace. The web pages do seem to be posting the login credentials to the server and the page is refreshing.  There are no JavaScript errors that I have found.

The one strange thing is that Joomla does not seem to be writing anything to the Logs folder. On each login attempt it should be appending a log file, but nothing at all is happening in that folder.

In some posts people have noted that this could be a permissions issue and cause a silent failure. Based on that I verified that the IIS_USERS account had full permissions to that folder.

I am beating my head against the wall on this.  Does anyone have an idea of what is going on or thoughts on how to debug the problem?

Comment: Have you amended your log file path to reflect the new virtual directory? Also, does the website display everything else ok on the front end - i.e only login issues

Comment: The log file path is set correctly.  I checked that several times.

Comment: This is old, but I just noticed it, as I've just started to use this StackExchange site. I wrote some blog articles about how I created a Joomla site on IIS, and this just might contain information that is of use to you: http://renniestechblog.com/information/15-joomla-on-iis-part-7-preparing-for-a-new-website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following some comments I found in other places I tried giving the YOURMACHINE\user account full permission to the site folders.  This actually fixed the problem, but I am not entirely comfortable with this from a security point of view. I was originally led to believe that the IIS_IUSR account was the one that was accessing the log folder, but this does not seem to be the case.

I think the issue is resolved, but I would welcome a better answer.